# emacsclient's "--script" option alternatives

Tags: emacsclient, script

To run an elisp file `hello.el` with emacs in cli, do simply

```
$ emacs --script hello.el
```

However, a naive try for `emacsclient` fails, as `--script` is not an option of `emacsclient`.

```
$ emacsclient --script
emacsclient: unrecognized option '--script'
Try 'emacsclient --help' for more information
```

**Question**: What is a good practice to evaluate an elisp file by a running emacsclient?

Comment: emacsclient -e "(load \"hello.el\")" ?

Comment: It worked.. sorry for the stupid question. Is it worth an answer?

Comment: It is not a stupid question. It can help some. Helping is never stupid.

Comment: Thank you. I hope it will help more people.

Comment: Please don't use tag `elisp` for questions about using Elisp. It's for questions about the nature of the language itself, compared to other languages, especially other Lisp dialects. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`emacsclient -e '(load "hello.el")'`